# Character encoding in vb6

Tags: vba, character-encoding, vb6

I have an application that stores txt, word and pdf files. It then displays the document to the user when the View option is selected.

We use the following code to convert the Unicode string to an array of bytes.

```
   aANSISString = StrConv(VerToInsert.FileBuffer, vbFromUnicode)
```

The document is viewed by the default application for that particular document type. Such as Microsoft Word for .doc files and so on. The problem I face is when the System locale changes to "Non-English" ,for example Arabic (Code page 1256), data is corrupted and is not view-able. 
But once the system locale is changed to English, everything works fine.

I don't face this problem with txt files. Could someone tell me the reason or point me to a reference page.

Comment: The `StrConv()` function has an optional 3rd argument: `LCID` that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Bob77's comment - 
From the Office dev center documentation about the third parameter LCID (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx):

LCID - Optional. The LocaleID, if different than the system LocaleID. (The system LocaleID is the default.)

StrConv is dependent on the system locale when you don't specify LCID.

You should always specify the LCID in case your users have a different locale than English.